# How to see php bytecode file

Tags: php, bytecode

I am doing it for learning purpose.
I have gone through many articles that php first convert its source code to bytecode, but i am not able to find a way to see the bytecode format, that how it looks like?

In java and C there are many ways to see bytecode file. but unable to find any article in php to see converted bytecode.

Answer (score 8):

To turn PHP code into a list of opcodes, you can use [`vld`](https://derickrethans.nl/projects.html#vld), the "Vulcan Logic Dumper" (available on [GitHub](https://github.com/derickr/vld) and [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/vld)).

The PHP documentation also maintains a [list of opcodes](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.php).

Also available is [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org), which allows you to input PHP code and view part of the `vld` dump on its results page.

Comment: I have gone through HHVM opcode documentation. HHVM has its own style of generating opcode. I do not use HHVM. I have by default php binaries downloaded from php.net. Its has its own interpreter. So i would like to see the bytecode generated by default php interpreter.

Comment: Yes, so you'll need to use `vld` to generate that output. Otherwise, PHP does not emit or save to disk its compiled opcode.

Comment: so that is my answer that php does not save the compiled opcode on to disk like java and C.
So should i finally assume that there is no way to see my generated opcode of my source code, except the third parties like HHVM and VLD

Comment: If you want the opcodes for your PHP code, you need to use `vld`. It will give you the opcodes PHP actually generates. HHVM is something entirely different, and you will probably get a different result using HHVM than you will with vld.

Comment: Ok i am satisfied with your answer. One thing more you can help me, that what is the name of default compiler being used in PHP 7 by default?

Comment: PHP *is* the compiler.

Comment: Zend Engine is used internally by PHP as a complier and runtime engine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102360/discussion-between-dhairya-lakhera-and-jbafford).

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you : https://github.com/facebook/hhvm

or search for facebook hiphop.

Comment: I have gone through the HHVM http://hhvm.com/blog/6323/the-journey-of-a-thousand-bytecodes. That article make me curious about how bytecode look likes.