# Get Number of CPU Instructions From Point A to Point B in A Script Compiles Into in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible?

Say I have some code in PHP:

```
... some PHP code here
```

Is there a way such that:

```
start_point();

... some PHP code here

end_point();
$v = dump_number_of_CPU_instructions();
echo $v;
```

I am expecting $v to be an integer that gives the number of CPU instructions that the code between start_point() and end_point() compiles into.

Comment: i'm little bit confuse on your question, i think you need `current resource usages` then read this manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.getrusage.php

Comment: There is very little correlation between lines of PHP and number of CPU cycles, as the system could schedule other tasks to run, even between two lines of your code. If the number of CPU cycles is pertinent to your application, or is a mission critical piece of data, you should be using a deterministic embedded system.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not compiled into machine code, but rather "bytecode", which are then interpreted by the PHP engine.  I don't think its practical to try to find the number of CPU instructions.

There are a number of tools floating around to get the bytecode (see John Bafford's response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146894/how-to-see-php-bytecode-file) for one).

The processing of the bytecode uses optimizations and caches, and does, of course, depend on the processor type, so I doubt it's practical to associate a CPU cycle count (or even time) associated with a particular bytecode.

Dealing with bytecode is not for the faint of heart.  Most people just try to time the PHP code and settle for that.